# Is there a Node.js based alternative to Puppet or Chef?

Tags: node.js, chef-infra, puppet, provisioning

Basically, the title says it all: Is there a Node.js based alternative to provisioning tools such as Puppet or Chef?

Comment: Please move to http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/, it's an interesting question.

Comment: This shouldn't be closed. The question is "is there" = "does it exist". The question can clearly be answered with a yes if a tool exists (link to the tool should be included as a proof). This is not a "which is the best tool" question.

Comment: Sigh.  I'm looking for this answer and it gets closed as 'off topic'.  It's a question; there exist answers.   Silly.

Answer (score 3):

Somebody please correct me if I am mistaken but there are a lot of other options. Please check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open-source_configuration_management_software). But none are node.js based.

UPDATE: There should be something that is open source http://docs.opsmezzo.com/